# Cast pointer to generic structure

Tags: c#, generics, pointers, structure, unsafe

I am traying to cast a pointer to a generic structure (blittable).
It all seems fine when I am doing with non-generic structures => then I am able to use Marshal.PtrToStructure(...) but that function does not receive generic structures (Why ?)

So I wrote the following:

```
public static object ReadValue<T>(IntPtr ptr) where T : struct
    {
        var dm = new DynamicMethod("$", typeof(T), Type.EmptyTypes);
            ILGenerator il = dm.GetILGenerator();
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, ptr.ToInt32());
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldobj, typeof(T));
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

            var func = (Func<T>)dm.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<T>));
            return func();
    }
```

But now it is something wrong with the Ldobj instruction. VS gives me:
Additional information: Operation could destabilize the runtime.

What am I doing wrong ?
Does anyone knows better approach to this problem (ptr to generic structure) or has spotted an error in this function?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this works with generic pointers but there is a way in .net to low level cast between types. It involves the StructLayout attribute and multiple fields at FieldOffset of 0.

http://netpl.blogspot.com/2010/10/is-net-type-safe.html

Comment: Thank you. I did not remember that. But unfortunately to good to be true: Could not load type 'PointerToStructure`1' from assembly 'ConsoleApplication1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because generic types cannot have explicit layout.

Comment: You could forget generics, pass it as an object and cast back in the caller.

Comment: I tried with an interface and it gives me an error (addresses cannot be overlapped...) . I can not use object because an object does not have specific size (if you mean for the FieldOffset(0)]