# Is there a way to find the size (in bytes) of any generic type variable in c# (I am using .NET 5)? (Marshal isn't working for generic type)

Tags: c#, generics, .net-5

What I want to do is something like the following code:

```
public int getSize<T>(T arg)
{
    int sizeInBytes = //Have to get the size of arg
    return sizeInBytes;
}
```

Comment: *In what way* is `Marshal` not working?

Comment: Seems identical to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18167216/size-of-generic-structure), which has a few solutions. If it's different in some way, then please update your question to explain why.